# What is the best way to handle Open Recent menu in OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa

My OSX app has various NSViewControllers which handle various data types. I added `openDocument:` and `saveDocument:` to these view controllers which get called when File->Open / File->Save are selected from the menu. I also call `NSDocumentController::noteNewRecentDocumentURL` to add the file URL to the File->Open Recent menu. But... when I select the file from Open Recent, it calls `NSApplicationDelegate::openFile:` instead of calling the first responder.

Do I need to connect the Open Recent menu item to the First Responder? Or can I check the file extension and route the message to the correct view controller? I understand that I'm supposed to use the First Responder chain, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Any tips in the documentation of `noteNewRecentDocumentURL`?

Comment: @Willeke Unfortunately the documentation isn't helpful. For now, I'm just using the singleton design pattern for the view controller and call methods directly. But, I'd rather do it the Apple way if I can.

Comment: The documentation of `noteNewRecentDocumentURL` says "Applications not based on NSDocument must also implement the application(_:openFile:) method in the application delegate to handle requests from the Open Recent menu command.".

Comment: @Willeke Thank you.  I added `NSApplicationDelegate::openFile:` to my app delegate as mentioned in my question. The problem is that it needs to go to the First Responder (the ViewController) just like `openDocument:` and `saveDocument:`.  But, how can I route the message to my ViewController? Should I use notifications? Should I get a pointer to the firstResponder and see if it is the right ViewController? Should I add an action to the RecentMenu so it sends to the firstResponder for me? There are lots of options here but I want to do it the Mac way and I'm unclear what that is.

Comment: Do you want to send the message to the first responder or to the right ViewController?

Comment: @Willeke I suppose it makes the most sense to send it to the first responder since that's how the File > Open and File > Save behave. But, I can't figure out how to send messages to the first responder which includes data as part of the message. And when I google on how to do this, most posts say that the app shouldn't send messages to the first responder but rather let the system do it instead. :-/

Comment: To send the file to the first responder, see [tryToPerform(_:with:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsresponder/1524516-trytoperform). To send the file to the right ViewController, add a method and call it.